# ASP MVC and Entity framework, need to insert foreign key the right way

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, foreign-key-relationship

I'm at the time trying to develop a web application in ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework, in my database do i have two related tables User and Role.

I using a repository pattern in my application, i have a page where i can add new users, and i am trying to parse a role to these new users. But unfortunately i cant get it to work.

I get following error message from VS, but i dont know how to fix the problem.

Cannot convert type 'int' to 'project.Models.Database.Role'

Model classes:

```
 public class User
 {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string UserMail { get; set; }
    public string UserPassword { get; set; }

    public virtual Role UserRole { get; set; }


 }

 public class Role
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    private List<User> users;

    public Role()
    {
        users = new List<User>();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<User> user { get; set; }


 }
```

ViewModel

```
 public class UserProfileViewModel
{
    //user
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("e-mail")]
    public string UserMail { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [DisplayName("adgangskode")]
    public string UserPassword { get; set; }

    public virtual Role UserRole { get; set; }


    [Required]
    [DisplayName("navn")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("telefonnummer")]
    public int Phone { get; set; }



}
```

Controller, i am trying to parse a role then the user is created, the string role.

```
 [ValidateInput(false)]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateClub(UserProfileViewModel viewModel, string role)
    {

        role = string.Empty;
        Role roles = db.Roles.SingleOrDefault(x => x.RoleName == "club");
        role = roles.Id.ToString();
        ViewBag.Test = role;

        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                _repository.CreateClub(viewModel, role);
                ViewBag.Succes = "Klub oprettet";
            }


        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            ModelState.AddModelError("", ex);
            ViewData["CreateError"] = "Unable to create; view innerexception";
        }


        return View();
    }
```

Interface

```
 public interface IClubRepository
{


    void CreateClub(UserProfileViewModel viewMode , string role);

}
```

Repository

```
 public void CreateClub(UserProfileViewModel viewModel, string role) // <- it wont parse a role
    {
        var user = new User()
        {


            UserMail = viewModel.UserMail,
            UserPassword = viewModel.UserPassword,
            UserRole = viewModel.UserRole.Id //<- Error comes here

        };

        var profile = new Profile()
        {
            Name = viewModel.Name,
            Phone = viewModel.Phone
        };

        user.profile = profile;


        db.Users.Add(user);
        db.Profiles.Add(profile);
        db.SaveChanges();

    }
```

Comment: `UserRole.Id` is returning an `int` not of type `Role` as you defined in the UserProfileViewModel.

Comment: can you define what you mean, i don't completely understand. 
Maybe give me an example :)

Comment: Instead of   public virtual Role UserRole { get; set; }, do you mean something like this,        public int  UserRole_Id { get; set; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line will return an int cause of `UserRole.Id`.

```
UserRole = viewModel.UserRole.Id //<- Error comes here
```

You need to change it to something like:

```
UserRole = viewModel.UserRole
```